# How to prevent overlap when changing a button's text?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following code to change the text of the button from "Button" to "Press Me!":

```
[self.aButton setTitle:@"Press Me!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

However, when I run the simulator, it shows the text of both and it overlaps. I tried constricting the button, but then after I ran the simulator again, there were two buttons, one with the default text of "Button", and the other with "Press Me!". I also tried deleting the default text of the button from the utilities panel, but that didn't work either.

How do I fix this?

```
ViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *aButton;

@end

ViewController.m
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.aButton setTitle:@"Press Me!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
}

@end
```

Comment: It sounds like there is a second button unrelated to aButton

Comment: perhaps showing more code would be helpful... it looks like you might be creating multiple instances of a button...l